# Reservation system with confirmation mail in PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Like the titles shows I'm making a reservation system in HTML/PHP. First a (HTML) form needs to be filled in and those values are passed to the reservation-send.php file. That .php file generates an email message with couple of values from the form and a confirmation link (incl. hash code) that will be send to the person who will confirm. When the link is pressed it will trigger another .php file, bevestiging.php. That file checks the hash code and email and if correct send another email that the confirmation has been made.

But always getting "error!". I think the output for my url confirmation link is the issue.. (see image)

**PHP - reservation-send.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'inc/securimage/securimage.php';

/////////////////////////////////////
// Change this email address ////////
$email = "test@test.be"; //make this test@test.be on purpose ;)

/////////////////////////////////////

$required = array('day', 'month', 'year', 'hour', 'minutes', 'ampm', 'name', 'email', 'captcha', 'phone', 'amount');
$response = array('status' => 'failed', 'errors'=>array());

if(isset($_POST['reservation'])) {
    foreach($_POST['reservation'] as $field => $value) {
        //check required field if empty
        if($value == '' && in_array($field, $required)) {
            $response['errors'][$field] = $field;
        }
    }

    //validate email
    if(!isset($response['errors']['email'])) {
        if(!filter_var($_POST['reservation']['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $response['errors']['email'] = 'email';
        }
    }

    //validate captcha
    if(!isset($response['errors']['captcha'])) {
        $securimage = new Securimage();
        if ($securimage->check($_POST['reservation']['captcha']) == false) {
            $response['errors']['captcha'] = 'captcha';
        }
    }

}

if(empty($response['errors'])) {
    $response['status'] = 'success';

    $data = $_POST['reservation'];

    //Generate email link

        //save mail of who made the reservation - get from form
        $email_reservering =$data['email'];

        //generate hash code
        $hash = md5($email_reservering);

        //generate link with hash code
        $link = "http://lanes.be/baronie/bevestiging.php?email=”.urlencode($email_reservering).”&hash=$hash";

    $headers = "";
    $message .= "Dag Lode en Eva, via de website kregen jullie een nieuwe reservatie, gelieve de persoon zo snel mogelijk een bevestigingsmail te sturen!";
    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message = $data['message'];
    $message .= "\n\n";

    $message .= " Telefoon: " . $data['phone'];
    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message .= " Lunch/Diner: " . $data['booking-type'];
    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message .= " Aantal personen: " . $data['amount'];
    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message .= " Email: " . $data['email'];

    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message .= " Datum: " . $data['day'];
    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message .= " Maand: " . $data['month'];
    $message .= " " . $data['year'];
    $message .= "\n\n";
    $message .= " Tijdstip: " . $data['hour'] . " " . $data['minutes'] . " " . $data['ampm'];
    $message .= "\n\n\n\n";
    $message .= "<a href='".$link."'>Bevestig</a>";

    $subject = 'Nieuwe reservatie via de website';
    $headers = 'From: '. $data['email']. "\r\n" .'Reply-To: '. $data['email']. "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'failed';
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

**PHP - bevestiging.php**

```
<?php

//retrieve email and hash code from link
$email_reservering = urldecode($_GET['email_reservering']);
$hash = $_GET['hash'];

//check if hash code matches

if (md5($email_reservering) == $hash)
{
    //succes    
    $headers = "";
    $message .= "reservering bevestigd!";
    $message .= "\n\n";

    $subject = 'Bevestiging reservering';

    if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

    } else {
        $response['status'] = 'failed';
    }
}
else
{
    //error
    echo "error!";
}

?>
```

**Output**
[image]

**Reason of error** (I think)

```
$link = "http://lanes.be/baronie/bevestiging.php?email=”.urlencode($email_reservering).”&hash=$hash";
```

or

```
$message .= "<a href='".$link."'>Bevestig</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$link is build the wrong way. Look at the quotes i replaced.
Change it to this:

```
$link = "http://lanes.be/baronie/bevestiging.php?email=".urlencode($email_reservering)."&hash=".$hash;
```

Also, you dont need to urldecode [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) variables

Comment: Changed it to what you said:

<a href='http://lanes.be/baronie/bevestiging.php?email=jens%40lanes.be&hash=17b3ef342ac5b2dafefeb9bfe8012f77'>Bevestig</a>

now looks like he's idd encoding the email aswell but still getting 'Error!' when clicking it.

Comment: Do you have any debug info? it's hard to say what is is without it.
BTW if its your own error output, then its because 
if (md5($email_reservering) == $hash) is failing...
It will fall into to else, where you echo error!

Comment: I got it working atleast with mailing it to the same emailadress as the one who needs to confirm the reservation. I need to find a way to retreive the email from the form and save it in the bevestiging.php file and send it to that address.

Comment: That is actually correct! after searching so much to just change couple of quotes gets you not thinking straight! :p thanks for the remark!